# How to Refresh ChartLabels when Manipulate BarChart Take Data Positions Change

Tags: manipulate, labeling, astronomy, charts

See attached sample code at the bottom of this post.

Under Manipulate, as I step through BarChart data using Take with different start/end positions, the chart of the data is refreshed, but the ChartLabels are not. 
So BarChart correctly labels the default start/end position data,
but when new start/end positions are selected, the BarChart correctly updates the chart for the new data, but the ChartLabels are not refreshed.
In the case, where star Names are the ChartLabels, labels still show the previous star names.

```
Manipulate[
 Switch[whichBarChart,
  4, BarChart[Take[category[[All, 4]], {startPosition, endPosition}],
    ChartLabels -> category[[All, label]],
    BarOrigin -> Left,
    ImageSize -> Large],
```

where start/end positions are defined as

```
{{startPosition, 1}, {1, 21, 41, 61, 81, 101, 121, 141, 161, 181, 
  201}},
{{endPosition, 21}, {21, 41, 61, 81, 101, 121, 141, 161, 181, 201, 
  221}},
```

label is defined as

```
{{label, 3}, {1 -> "Name", 3 -> "SpectralType", 12 -> "Constellation",
   4 -> "BVColorIndex", 5 -> "Temperature", 6 -> "Mass", 
  7 -> "Luminosity", 8 -> "AbsoluteMagnitude"}},
```

and whichBarChart is defined as

```
{{whichBarChart, 6, "Choose BarChart"},
 {4 -> "BVColorIndex", 5 -> "Temperature", 6 -> "Mass", 
  7 -> "Luminosity", 8 -> "AbsoluteMagnitude",
  15 -> "SortTemperature", 16 -> "SortMass", 17 -> "SortLuminosity", 
  18 -> "SortAbsoluteMagnitude"}},
```

and AstronomicalData categories are defined as

```
{{category, importAllSubgiant }, {
  importAllClassA -> "ClassA",
  importAllClassB -> "ClassB",
  importAllClassF -> "ClassF",
  importAllClassG -> "ClassG",
  importAllClassM -> "ClassM",
  importAllClassO -> "ClassO",
  importAllSubgiant -> "Subgiant",
  importAllNormalGiant -> "NormalGiant",
  importAllSupergiant -> "Supergiant"}}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Sample code:

```
    classA10 = {{"Sirius", 48915, "A1Vm", 0.009`, 1.6`, 2.6`, 
    40.`}, {"Vega", 172167, "A0Vvar", 0.`, 1.7`, 2.9`, 50.`},
   {"Altair", 187642, "A7V", 0.221`, 1.4`, 1.8`, 9.`}, {"Fomalhaut", 
    216956, "A3V", 0.145`, 1.5`, 2.2`, 20.`}, {"Deneb", 197345, 
    "A2Ia", 0.092`, 1.6`, 20.`, 120000.`}, {"Castor", 60179, "A2Vm", 
    0.034`, 1.6`, 2.4`, 30.`}, {"Miaplacidus", 80007, "A2IV", 0.07`, 
    1.6`, 2.8`, 60.`}, {"Menkalinan", 40183, "A2V", 0.076`, 1.6`, 
    2.4`, 30.`}, {"Alhena", 47105, "A0IV", 0.`, 1.7`, 3.5`, 
    90.`}, {"Î\.b4 Velorum", 74956, "A1V", 0.043`, 1.6`, 2.6`, 40.`}};

classB10 = {{"Rigel", 34085, "B8Ia", -0.03`, 2.5`, 23.`, 
200000.`}, {"Achernar", 10144, "B3Vpe", -0.158`, 3.3`, 7.6`, 
3000.`}, {"Hadar", 122451, "B1III", -0.231`, 4.6`, 16.`, 
80000.`}, {"Acrux", 108248, "B0.5IV", -0.243`, 4.8`, 17.`, 
60000.`}, {"Spica", 116658, "B1V", -0.235`, 4.4`, 14.`, 
16000.`}, {"Mimosa", 111123, "B0.5III", -0.238`, 4.8`, 18.`, 
100000.`}, {"Regulus", 87901, "B7V", -0.087`, 2.2`, 4.4`, 
300.`}, {"Adhara", 52089, "B2II", -0.211`, 4.2`, 11.`, 
90000.`}, {"Shaula", 158926, "B1.5IV+...", -0.231`, 4.2`, 13.`, 
30000.`}, {"Bellatrix", 35468, "B2III", -0.224`, 4.2`, 13.`, 
40000.`}};

Manipulate[


Switch[whichBarChart,
  5, BarChart[Take[category[[All, 5]], {startPosition, endPosition}],
    ChartLabels -> category[[All, label]],
    BarOrigin -> Left,
    ImageSize -> Large],
  6, BarChart[
        Take[category[[All, 6]], {startPosition, endPosition}],
    ChartLabels -> category[[All, label]],
    BarOrigin -> Left,
    ImageSize -> Large],
  7, BarChart[Take[category[[All, 7]], {startPosition, endPosition}],
    ChartLabels -> category[[All, label]],
    BarOrigin -> Left,
    ImageSize -> Large]
  ],
 {{startPosition, 1}, {1, 6}},
 {{endPosition, 5}, {5, 10}},
 {{whichBarChart, 6, "Choose BarChart"},
  {5 -> "Temperature", 6 -> "Mass", 7 -> "Luminosity"}},
 {{label, 1}, {1 -> "Name", 3 -> "SpectralType"}},
 {{category, classA10}, {
   classA10 -> "ClassA",
   classB10 -> "ClassB"
   }}
 ]
ListPicker[Dynamic[a],
  {
   classA10 -> "ClassA",
   classB10 -> "ClassB"
   }
  ];
```

Comment: Posted sample code at the bottom of this posting

Comment: "In the case, where star Names are the ChartLabels, labels still show the previous star names." Perhaps I am misunderstanding, but isn't that the correct and expected behavior? the "Choose Bar Chart" variable selects which property of the selected stars to plot, but does not influence the selection of a subset of stars, or so it seems to me at least. When you select e.g. another star class, then the names change. Could you clarify the question?

Comment: Select startPosition 1 and endPosition 5. Notice the star names. Now select startPosition 6 and endPosition 10. The star names did not change. Select startPosition 1 and endPosition 10 to see all star names

Comment: What I want to do is build steps of 20 across a sample of 200 for each star category using startPosition and endPosition. 1-20, 21-40, etc show the correct BarChart data, but the star name labels are the same across each step of 20 stars. If I use other fields for label besides Name, like SpectralClass, the same thing happens. Same 20 SpectralClasses across each step of 20.

Comment: Additional information, if you change the defaults for startPosition and endPosition from {1,5} to {6,10}, the star names are still those of positions {1,5}. Even if you replace the variables startPosition and endPosition with values{6,10}. While 1-10 works and shows all star names.

Comment: My guess is that the problem is related to the ChartLabels coding [[All, label]] which produces all star Names, but BarChart uses Take, that takes a subset of values that conflicts with ChartLabels setting of All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a refactored / slimmed version of the code in your answer:

```
Manipulate[
 With[{selected = category[[startPosition ;; endPosition]]},
   BarChart[
     selected[[All, whichBarChart]], 
     ChartLabels -> selected[[All, label]], 
     BarOrigin -> Left, ImageSize -> Large
   ]
 ],
 {{startPosition, 1}, {1, 6}},
 {{endPosition, 5}, {5, 10}},
 {{whichBarChart, 6, "Choose BarChart"}, {5 -> "Temperature", 6 -> "Mass", 7 -> "Luminosity"}},
 {{label, 1}, {1 -> "Name", 3 -> "SpectralType"}},
 {{category, classA10}, {classA10 -> "ClassA", classB10 -> "ClassB"}}
]
```

The above produces the same output, but avoids repetitive code.

Comment: That worked great!  Thank you!

Comment: Ran into a gotcha. In the full application there are actually two types of charts:

Comment: In the full application there are actually two types of charts where 4,5,6,7,8 use the 1st type of BarChart and 15,16,17,18 use a sorted BarChart:

Comment: {4 -> "BVColorIndex", 5 -> "Temperature", 6 -> "Mass", 
 7 -> "Luminosity", 8 -> "AbsoluteMagnitude",
 15 -> "SortTemperature", 16 -> "SortMass", 17 -> "SortLuminosity", 
 18 -> "SortAbsoluteMagnitude"}

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Removed Take and All, replacing with Range[startPosition,endPosition]

```
Manipulate[
 Switch[whichBarChart,
  5, BarChart[category[[Range[startPosition, endPosition], 5]],
    ChartLabels -> 
    category[[Range[startPosition, endPosition], label]],
    BarOrigin -> Left,
    ImageSize -> Large],
  6, BarChart[category[[Range[startPosition, endPosition], 6]],
    ChartLabels -> 
    category[[Range[startPosition, endPosition], label]],
    BarOrigin -> Left,
    ImageSize -> Large],
  7, BarChart[category[[Range[startPosition, endPosition], 7]],
    ChartLabels -> 
    category[[Range[startPosition, endPosition], label]],
    BarOrigin -> Left,
    ImageSize -> Large]
  ],
 {{startPosition, 1}, {1, 6}},
 {{endPosition, 5}, {5, 10}},
 {{whichBarChart, 6, "Choose BarChart"},
  {5 -> "Temperature", 6 -> "Mass", 7 -> "Luminosity"}},
 {{label, 1}, {1 -> "Name", 3 -> "SpectralType"}},
 {{category, classA10}, {
   classA10 -> "ClassA",
   classB10 -> "ClassB"
   }}
 ]
ListPicker[Dynamic[a],
 {
  classA10 -> "ClassA",
  classB10 -> "ClassB"
  }
 ]
```